# Shiro HttpSession in SessionListener?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets, shiro

I'm trying to replace the session management (Currently handled by Catalina/Tomcat) of my webapp to shiro native session management.

This should be a fairly easy job, as is adverted by the shiro website:

> Transparent HttpSession support - If you are using Shiro's native
>   sessions, we have implemented HTTP Session API and the Servlet 2.5 API
>   so you don't have to change any of your existing web code to use
>   Shiro.

So after, you replaced the local Session Manager with Shiro's `DefaultWebSessionManager` everything should work out of the box.

This is also the case for my webapp, except for a certain `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`. This Listener no longer gets events since using Shiro's session management.

No worries I thought! Shiro offers it's own `org.apache.shiro.session.SessionListener` interface that can be linked to the session manager.

However, this interface differs a lot from `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener`. There are no longer `HttpSession` objects passed, instead the Shiro Listener passes it's own  `org.apache.shiro.session.Session` objects with the events.

My existing implementation works ofcourse only with `HttpSession` objects. I found out that a Shiro `Session` can be transformed to a `HttpSession`:

```
// HttpServletRequest currentRequest;
// ServletContext servletContext;
// Session session;
HttpSession httpSession = new ShiroHttpSession(session, currentRequest, servletContext);
```

However there is no way to acces the HttpServletRequest and servletContext from the Shiro `SessionListener`.

Any ideas how to solve this problem, e.g. can you answer one of these two question?

1. Why is the old `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` no longer
   called?
2. How do I transform Shiro `Session` objects to `HttpSession`
   objects in the shiro `SessionListener`?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is the old `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` no longer
>   called?

As you've explained, Session management is now handled through Shiro instead of through the Servlet container. As such, even if your `HttpSessionListener` is registered, your Servlet container is just not creating any `HttpSession` objects and therefore not using any of the `HttpSessionListener` callbacks.

> How do I transform Shiro `Session` objects to `HttpSession` objects in the
>   shiro `SessionListener`?

You don't and you shouldn't.

If you explain what you want to do with the `HttpSession`, we might be able to find alternatives.

Comment: Simpy put, all code in my old SessionListener is written to work with HttpSessions. How can I reuse this code without having to refactor it all to use Shiro Session objects? This will be quite a lot of work.

Comment: @KarstenDaemen What `HttpSession` methods are you using? Shiro's `Session` has attribute setters and getters as well, but obviously those aren't available to JSPs and such.